# python regexp parse js file

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a js file which with comments in jsdoc style:

```
/****************************************************************************
 Copyright (c) 2010-2012 cocos2d-x.org
 Copyright (c) 2008-2010 Ricardo Quesada
 Copyright (c) 2011      Zynga Inc.

 http://www.cocos2d-x.org
 ****************************************************************************/

cc.g_NumberOfDraws = 0;

//Possible OpenGL projections used by director
/**
 * sets a 2D projection (orthogonal projection)
 * @constant
 * @type Number
 */
cc.DIRECTOR_PROJECTION_2D = 0;

/**
 * sets a 3D projection with a fovy=60, znear=0.5f and zfar=1500.
 * @constant
 * @type Number
 */
cc.DIRECTOR_PROJECTION_3D = 1;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * @class
 * @extends cc.Class
 */
cc.Director = cc.Class.extend(/** @lends cc.Director# */{
    //Variables
    _landscape:false,
    _nextDeltaTimeZero:false,
    /**
     * <p>
     * </p>
     */
    popToRootScene:function () {
        // ...
    },

    /**
     * <p>
     * </p>
     * @param {Number} level
     */
    popToSceneStackLevel: function (level) {
        // ...
    }
});

/**
 * returns a shared instance of the director
 * @function
 * @return {cc.Director}
 */
cc.Director.getInstance = function () {
    // ...
};

/**
 * is director first run
 * @type Boolean
 */
cc.firstRun = true;
```

Now I want to extract all the **variables and functions with jsdoc comment** using python regexp.

For the example above the segments I want to extract are:

segment 1:

```
/**
 * sets a 2D projection (orthogonal projection)
 * @constant
 * @type Number
 */
cc.DIRECTOR_PROJECTION_2D = 0;
```

segment 2:

```
/**
 * sets a 3D projection with a fovy=60, znear=0.5f and zfar=1500.
 * @constant
 * @type Number
 */
cc.DIRECTOR_PROJECTION_3D = 1;
```

segment 3:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * </p>
 */
popToRootScene:function () {
    // ...
},
```

segment 4:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * @param {Number} level
 */
popToSceneStackLevel: function (level) {
    // ...
}
```

segment 5:

```
/**
 * returns a shared instance of the director
 * @function
 * @return {cc.Director}
 */
cc.Director.getInstance = function () {
    // ...
};
```

segment 6:

```
/**
 * is director first run
 * @type Boolean
 */
cc.firstRun = true;
```

As you can see what I want is to extract all the variables, instance functions, class functions which has a **jsdoc style comment** and make a list kind like:

variables:

```
name: cc.DIRECTOR_PROJECTION_2D   type: number
name: cc.DIRECTOR_PROJECTION_3D   type: number
```

instance functions:

```
name: popToRootScene    param: xxxx   return: xxxx
name: popToSceneStackLevel   param: number - level   return: xxxx
```

class functions:

```
name: cc.Director.getInstance   param: xxxx   return: cc.Director
```

I tried to parse class functions of the file using:

```
re.findall('\s*/\*\*.*?\*/.*?function.*?};', content, re.S)
```

and instance functions:

```
re.findall('\s*/\*\*.*?\*/.*?function.*?},', content, re.S)
```

but failed ...

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

**Updated:**

```
re.findall(r"(^(?P<identation> *)/\*\*.*$(\r?\n?^(?P=identation) * .*$)*\r?\n?(?P=identation) \*/\r?\n?^.*$)", content, re.M)
```

The pattern works great except when there is empty line in between the comment such as:

```
/**1
2

3
 */
cc.Node = cc.Class.extend(/** @lends cc.Node# */{

});
```

Comment: Copyright (c) 2010-2012 cocos2d-x.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not match bracket expressions with regular expressions. They need context-free expressions.

You can match the first line after the comment or anything until a `;` is there.

```
for x in re.findall(r"(^(?P<identation> *)/\*\*\s*$(\r?\n?^(?P=identation) * .*$)*\r?\n?(?P=identation) \*/\s*^.*$)", s, re.MULTILINE):
    print("-" * 40)
    print(x[0])


----------------------------------------
/**
 * sets a 2D projection (orthogonal projection)
 * @constant
 * @type Number
 */
cc.DIRECTOR_PROJECTION_2D = 0;
----------------------------------------
/**
 * sets a 3D projection with a fovy=60, znear=0.5f and zfar=1500.
 * @constant
 * @type Number
 */
cc.DIRECTOR_PROJECTION_3D = 1;
----------------------------------------
/**
 * <p>
 * </p>
 * @class
 * @extends cc.Class
 */
cc.Director = cc.Class.extend(/** @lends cc.Director# */{
----------------------------------------
    /**
     * <p>
     * </p>
     */
    popToRootScene:function () {
----------------------------------------
    /**
     * <p>
     * </p>
     * @param {Number} level
     */
    popToSceneStackLevel: function (level) {
----------------------------------------
/**
 * returns a shared instance of the director
 * @function
 * @return {cc.Director}
 */
cc.Director.getInstance = function () {
----------------------------------------
/**
 * is director first run
 * @type Boolean
 */

cc.firstRun = true;
```

Is the best that I could get. In the last line you can see that empty lines in between are also welcome.

Comment: Thanks for you help, it works great except that when there is an empty line in between the comment part, the match will fail ~ see the update of the question ~

Comment: Modified the regex accordingly. Have alook at the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and sorry for my bad example (the ex is updated) ~  there is some text in between the comment along with the empty lines ~